# parse cloud code http request does not work for ionic push api with headers and data

Tags: parse-platform, ionic-framework, httprequest, parse-cloud-code

I'm trying to make a http request in parse cloud code which i thought should be very easy to do. I'm following the [documentation on the push API](http://docs.ionic.io/docs/push-api-examples)

However I cannot get it to work. I have the following code:

```js
var privateKey = 'xxxx:';
var tokens = ['yyyyy1','yyyyy2'];
var appId = 'zzzzz';
// Encode your key
var Buffer = require('buffer').Buffer;
var b = new Buffer(privateKey);

var auth = b.toString('base64');
// Build the request object
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
  method: "POST",
  url: "https://push.ionic.io/api/v1/push",
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'X-Ionic-Application-Id': appId,
    'Authorization': 'basic ' + auth
  },
  data: {
    "tokens": tokens,
    "notification": {
      "alert":"sent by ionic push through Parse cloud code!"
    }
  }
}).then(function(httpResponse) {
  console.log(httpResponse);
  response.success(httpResponse.text);
}, function(err) {
  console.log(err);
  response.error(err);
})
```

In the log, it returns:

```
Result: {"uuid":"95b3a0fb-6fb6-4fc9-032d-486338579455","status":400,"headers":{"Access-Control-Allow-Headers":"Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept","Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"71","Content-Type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","Date":"Fri, 28 Aug 2015 09:01:33 GMT","Etag":"W/\"47-/thoVeqbHE/JKNAoGBGTNQ\"","Server":"Cowboy","Via":"1.1 vegur","X-Powered-By":"Express"},"text":"{\"result\":\"error\",\"message\":\"A list of tokens or user_ids is required\"}","data":{"result":"error","message":"A list of tokens or user_ids is required"},"buffer":[123,34,114,101,115,117,108,116,34,58,34,101,114,114,111,114,34,44,34,109,101,115,115,97,103,101,34,58,34,65,32,108,105,115,116,32,111,102,32,116,111,107,101,110,115,32,111,114,32,117,115,101,114,95,105,100,115,32,105,115,32,114,101,113,117,105,114,101,100,34,125],"cookies":{}}
I2015-08-28T09:01:33.951Z]{"uuid":"95b3a0fb-6fb6-4fc9-032d-486338579455","status":400,"headers":{"Access-Control-Allow-Headers":"Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept","Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"71","Content-Type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","Date":"Fri, 28 Aug 2015 09:01:33 GMT","Etag":"W/\"47-/thoVeqbHE/JKNAoGBGTNQ\"","Server":"Cowboy","Via":"1.1 vegur","X-Powered-By":"Express"},"text":"{\"result\":\"error\",\"message\":\"A list of tokens or user_ids is required\"}","data":{"result":"error","message":"A list of tokens or user_ids is required"},"buffer":{"0":123,"1":34,"2":114,"3":101,"4":115,"5":117,"6":108,"7":116,"8":34,"9":58,"10":34,"11":101,"12":114,"13":114,"14":111,"15":114,"16":34,"17":44,"18":34,"19":109,"20":101,"21":115,"22":115,"23":97,"24":103,"25":101,"26":34,"27":58,"28":34,"29":65,"30":32,"31":108,"32":105,"33":115,"34":116,"35":32,"36":111,"37":102,"38":32,"39":116,"40":111,"41":107,"42":101,"43":110,"44":115,"45":3... (truncated)
```

The response:

> A list of tokens or user_ids is required

does not make sense to me. I have tried different types for tokens but none of them worked.

Could anyone tell me why such a simple POST does not work in Parse cloud code?

Comment: Why are you using both parse and ionic services?

Answer (score 0):

I have such a solution working in my app. The request for me is:

```
 var req = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'https://push.ionic.io/api/v1/push',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                'X-Ionic-Application-Id': appId,
                'Authorization': 'basic ' + auth
            },
            body: {
                "tokens": tokens,
                "notification": {
                    "alert": mensaje
                    }
                }
            }
        };
```

I think you are putting the object into "data" property, while it should be "body".

Comment: How do you send this request. I did it using `$http({req})` but I get 400 Bad Request